# What word for "itself" would I use and why?

Tags: english-to-german

I have looked into this quite a bit and always get confused about what word I should use and when to use it. Most recently with the word *itself*. I have looked into it but cannot find anything useful on the topic.

The sentence being:

> Finally the rugby ball ate itself

Comment: Sorry, but since the last time you asked this question https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40922/what-word-for-finally-would-i-use-and-is-it-a-time-expression-and-what-word-for it hasn't improved at all. It's still a mess and not resolvable.

Comment: @Janka I'm sorry thatit is a mess how can i refine it

Comment: Your example sentence doesn't make a lot of sense to me (nor, I guess, to anyone else). Why on earth should a rugby ball eat itself?

Comment: I don't know anything about eating balls, but probably it would help if you write more context, e.g. the sentences before and thereafter. If eating balls is a methapher only known in the inner circle, you could break the circle and describe the methapher.

Comment: What words for 'itself" did you find in a dictionary and why didn't you find them useful?

Comment: Rugbybälle essen sich selbst in Comicstrips, Trickfilmen und 3D-Animationen am laufenden Band, da muss man sich nicht so anstellen. Der Satz ist jedermann verständlich. Die Antwort ist, dass es nicht ein Wort im Deutschen ist, sondern dass es zwei sind: "Sich selbst".  Mehr ist dazu nicht zu sagen und sollte in jedem Wörterbuch zu finden sein. "Schließlich aß sich der Rugbyball selbst." Oder "Am Ende ...".